# how to retrieve value from the database on page load in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have two dropdowns in my update form. One for geopolitical zones and the other for states (states dropdown is dependent on geopolitical zones dropdown). i know that by default, if am updating a record in yii, the stored value of the state is selected in the states dropdown. 
Now am working with dependent dropdowns, on page load, i make an ajax call to update the values on the states dropdown based on the value of the geopolitical zone. This works. 
Now i want to set the selected value of the states dropdown to be same as that in the database. In my javascript i tried setting the value of the states dropdown to the known value and this works. So my question is how do i retrieve the value of the state from the database so i can parse it on page load to my ajax call?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'gpz_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'gpz_id', CHtml::listData(GPZ::model()->findAll(), 'gpz_id', 'gpz'),
                    array(
                        'prompt'=>'Select Geopolitical Zone',
                        'ajax'=>array(
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'url'=>CController::createURL('state/sortbygpz'),
                            'update'=>'#Project_state_id',
                            'data'=>  array('gpz_id'=>'js:this.value'),  
                            'success'=> 'js:function(msg) {
                                $("#Project_state_id").html(msg);
                            }'
                                        )
                    )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'gpz_id'); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'state_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'state_id', array(), array('prompt'=>'Select Geopolitical Zone First')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'state_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var gpz = $('#Project_gpz_id').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
           url: '<?php echo CController::createURL('/state/sortbygpz'); ?>',
           data: {gpz_id: gpz},
           update: $('#Project_state_id'),
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#Project_state_id').html(msg);
$('#Project_state_id').val("31"); //i set the selected value to a known state id
            }
            error: function() {
                alert(error);
            } 

    }); 

});
```

Comment: `var state_id = "<?=$model->state_id;?>";` to retrieve value in js. So you'll have `$('#Project_state_id').val(state_id);`.

Comment: Try one of these: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/429/an-easy-solution-for-dependent-dropdownlist-using-ajax/ or http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/

Comment: Thanks ineersa, worked like a charm ;)